# Reflection, transmission, absorption...how to calculate them?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, radiation

I was wondering whether there is an equation that enables me to calculate the reflection, transmission, absorption and polarization, when the electric field everywhere is given?

Consider this: You have solved the full Mie scattering process, so incident field, the field in the sphere and the scattered field are known. How can one calculate those quantities then?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can calculate absorption through integration of the Poynting vector over the surface of the sphere. I am not sure there are any standard general definitions of transmission and reflection for diffraction on a sphere.